Run AOSP cuttlefish x86_64 on a remote machine and view webrtc output on another machine via browser
I have managed to run Android 14 cuttlefish virtual device for x86 on my local machine and view it's GUI on Chrome browser on my local machine via webRTC by connecting to https://localhost:8443 address.
The next goal is to run the cuttlefish on a remote machine and access it's output in wen browser running on my local machine. Has anyone done that before ? The android official docs do not seem to discuss this use case.

It is unlikely to have anything much to do with Cuttlefish or AOSP. My guess is that you will need to identify some sort of proxy that can run on your remote machine that is open to the Internet and forwards connection requests, etc. to the Cuttlefish WebRTC address and port.

This particular use case should be no different than setting up a server on one machine and checking if you can access it on another in your local network. If you are hosting in the cloud then network configuration is handled by your cloud provider. If I'm mistaken, please provide details about what you tried.

I run the Cuttlefish Virtual Device (CVD) in a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) VM instance and access the virtual device remotely via a local browser. After launching the CVD, I use GCP's Identity Aware Proxy (IAP) to tunnel the remote port 8443 to a local ephemeral port. For example:
gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel vm1 8443 --local-host-port=localhost:50000
After the tunnel is established, go to https://localhost:50000 on the local browser to access the cuttlefish device.
If you're not using GCP, the same port forwarding approach can be implemented in a number of ways. For example, with ssh:
ssh -L 50000:localhost:8443 user@server
